# Realm collection query

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I want to build a query in realm(java) that satisfies this condition:
All the books that have a tag with type X and name like Y.
Here my realm classes:

```
class Book extends RealmObject {

    public RealmList<Tag> tags;

    public int fileType;

    public String title;
}

class Tag extends RealmObject {

    public Book book;

    public int type;

    public String name;
}
```

I have to use a query based on Book, so the query must begin like this:

```
realm.where(Book.class)
```

But I can't build query as I want.
I tried this:

```
realm.where(Book.class)
  .equalTo("tags.type", X)
  .contains("tags.name", Y)
  .findAll();
```

This query means books that any of it's tags.type equals to X and any of it's tags.name contains Y.

But I wanna apply both condition to same Tag object.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: hi hojjat. Could you explain the problem in another way? cannot figure out what exactly u r looking for. Ur current query as far as i know will return all books which have a tag type of X or books containing the name Y.

Comment: what do you mean by applying both conditions to same tag object?

Comment: Hi vishnus. Thanks for reply. My query returns all books which have a tag type of X or tag name contains Y. Suppose I have a book with two Tags. first tag like this {type = X, name = "test"} and second one: {type = Z, name = "Y"}. This query returns this book as a result But It's not what I want. I wanna both conditions apply to same Tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link queries can be a bit hard to wrap your head around, but we have a full example with explanations here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries

In your case you need to rewrite it into this:

```
realm.where(Book.class)
  .equalTo("tags.type", X)
  .findAll().where()
  .contains("tags.name", Y)
  .findAll();
```

Comment: Thank you Christian. This solve the problem I told. But I have another conditions which must be applied, so I have to wrap every condition group in beginGroup() and endGroup. But apparently I should close group before findAll method. Can you give a solution for that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem, but if and `beginGroup` must be matched by a `endGroup` for it to be a valid query.

Comment: I have to call endGroup after findAll method because I have another conditions that must be applied like this: realm.where(Book.class).beginGroup()....findAll().endGroup()

Comment: Just move it to right before the `findAll()`: `realm.where(Book.class).beginGroup()....endGroup().findAll()`

Comment: Here's the complete query: I wanna get all books that: (fileType == 1 and title like "pattern") or (fileType == 2 and title like "pattern") or (fileType = 1 and have a tag with(type = X and name = Y)) or (fileType = 2 and have a tag with(type = X and name = Y))

Comment: I realized that there is noway in realm to set internal predicates before you get result like where() method used above. Thanks Christian

Answer (score 0):

```
realm.where(Animal.class)
  .equalTo("birds.type", 2)
  .or()
  .equalTo("birds.species.value", 3)
  .findAll();
```

use the or() function to combine multiple queries at the same time